# Does Ordering BY primary key help query performance when joining table to query

Tags: mysql

Wondering about performance when joining a table with a query. Does the ORDER BY help?

For example if I am joining a user_stat table where the primary key is user_id, order_type with a selection of orders.

```
SELECT user_stats.*, order_stat.num_orders as orders_in_range FROM
  user_stats INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id , order_type, count(order_id) as num_orders FROM orders 
    WHERE order_date > '2020-01-01 00:00:00' 
    GROUP BY user_id, order_type
    !!! ORDER BY user_id, order_type !!!
  ) as order_stat ON user_stats.user_id = order_stat.user_id AND user_stats.order_type = order_stat.order_type
```

I understand that there are other ways to write this. I am just wondering if the ORDER BY speeds things up, slows them down or has no effect. Or if there is some way to let the optimizer know that they are in order so can do things faster?

I am using mySQL 5.7

Comment: The version of MySQL will probably help as well as the table definitions.

Comment: Please read https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions and edit your question

Comment: Don't know about MySQL, but in an adult DBMS an `ORDER BY` clause in a subselect (in the absence of `LIMIT` or similar) will likely be simply ignored by the optimiser.

Comment: Please fix the typo(s).  I see one with `num_orders`.

Comment: Caching?  Run each form of the query twice -- to see if the timing diff is just due to caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, specifying an `ORDER BY` clause is an extra operation that *can* result (and generally does) in more work for your queries, even queries that `JOIN` two tables together with an `ORDER BY` clause that sorts the data to the order of the `JOIN` predicates.

The **query optimizer** is (*usually*) smart enough to know when to internally sort the data to most efficiently `JOIN` two tables together, and will do so dependent on the indexes of those tables (because indexing already sorts the data) that it's going to use for the query.

So it's theoretically possible that the **query optimizer** might choose an index that is sorted differently (and/or results in a different sort operation) than the one you specified in your `ORDER BY` clause which will result in extra work for the query to be processed and the data to be served. And in the best case, generally, you're not adding any benefit by specifying an unneeded `ORDER BY` clause even if it's not causing any harm.

Answer (score 1):

A guess...  There are two ways to do a `GROUP BY`:

- Sort the data (according to the `GROUP BY` clauses), then scan the table to get the `COUNTs`.
- Build a temporary (and hopefully small) hash in RAM, then scan the table gathering the `COUNTs` in it.

Some other notes:

- The Optimizer may not know which of the above is faster; hence it may pick the slower one.
- The existence of identical (or at least 'compatible') `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`, then the first method of doing `GROUP BY` is likely to be better.  This is because it automatically performs the `ORDER BY` without any effort.
- The Optimizer is free to ignore `ORDER BY` in a subquery (when there is not also a `LIMIT`).  This is because the definition of any table (including a subquery) is an unordered set of rows.
- It *may* be that the Optimizer noticed the matching `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` before noticing that the `ORDER BY` can be ignored.

I would like to get to the bottom of this confusing lists of things.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for each formulation.  (And also run each query twice -- to avoid caching issues.)